# Trying to get machine learning lib set up on a 290X

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, arrayfire, amd-gpu

I am having some difficulty finding a library with which to explore machine learning/ai. I have a pair of R9 290x's, and can't seem to find a lib which works well for it.

First I tried array-fire, which has excellent CPU performance, but poor GPU performance for machine learning, as demonstrated on the benchmarks in the machine_learning sample folder.

I looked into rocm and MIOpen, I tried the [hip enabled tensorflow](https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/hiptensorflow) but found it is not supported on the 290x generations. I found someone working on [llvm-amdgpu suppport](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10437) for tensorflow as well, but it doesn't look ready yet

I looked into accelerate for haskell, and found an issue regarding the [amdgpu backend](https://github.com/AccelerateHS/accelerate-llvm/issues/7), but it also looks not ready.

Maybe I haven't been searching broadly enough? But from what I can tell, almost everything runs on cuda, and I can't afford a new GPU for this right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you asked the question, AMD did not support Hawaii GPU's with their [rocm](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm) driver and compute stack.
Since then support has been added for these older GPU's.

AMD has made a tensorflow port which installs and functions the same as CUDA tensorflow ([amd's port](https://gpuopen.com/rocm-tensorflow-1-8-release/)). However it doesn't support anything older than gfx803 (Fiji, such as R9 Fury).

I have an R9 290 and it is works with the latest rocm drivers from AMD's repo, but not with the AMD tensorflow port. This is the error I get:

`2018-08-16 12:10:58.529311: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290], pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0) with AMDGPU ISA gfx701. The minimum required AMDGPU ISA is gfx803.`